# Find the Fourier series of $\sin^3(x)$ on $[-\pi,\pi]$

Tags: real-analysis, analysis

I'm having trouble integrating $B_{n}=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi}\sin^{3}t \,\sin(nt)\,dt$.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using trig identities to rewrite $\sin^3(x)$ as $A\sin(x)+B\sin(2x)+C\sin(3x)$. Then there's your series right there.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Use: 1) $4\sin^3(t)=3 \sin(t)-\sin(3t)$

2) Use the formula for $\sin(a)\sin(b)$

Comment: After using that identity, I get that $B_n=0$. Isn't this suppose to be non-zero since $sin^3(\theta)$ is an odd function?

Comment: There is nothing more to compute, the Fourier series is nothing more nor less than that sum of sine terms (divided by 4).

Comment: @LutzL, But then $A_0=0$, so is $B_n$, then how do we represent the function as a trigonometric polynomial?

Comment: I see $B_1=\frac34$ and $B_3=-\frac14$, your function is already represented as trigonometric polynomial?

Comment: @LutzL, Don't we get 0/0 for $n=1,3$?

Comment: Where, why? As was said multiple times, there are no integrals to evaluate, the final result is already in the formula of the answer. Note also that $\cos(0\cdot x)=1$ and the integral of $1$ is $x$.

Comment: @LutzL, I tried that way now. I get that $f(x)$~$(1/2)[sinx+sin3x]$. But that isn't the formula for $sin^3t$. I evaluated $\int(cos(o))dt$ from $-\pi$ to $\pi$.

Comment: This should give the value $2π$, and since you have to divide by $2π$ to get the coefficient, $b_1=1$.